# Cobol recursive program nth Fibonacci number

Tags: recursion, fibonacci, cobol

I'm trying to code a logic for nth Fibonacci number by using recursive technique in COBOL. Below is the code. But I'm getting wrong results where could be the problem?

For the input 7, it's giving results as `ret-fib= 01 ret-fib= 00 ret-fib= 01 ret-fib= 01 ret-fib= 03 ret-fib= 01 ret-fib= 00 ret-fib= 01 ret-fib= 03 ret-fib= 01 ret-fib= 00 ret-fib= 01 ret-fib= 01 ret-fib= 03 ret-fib= 05 ret-fib= 01 ret-fib= 00 ret-fib= 01 ret-fib= 01 ret-fib= 03 ret-fib= 01 ret-fib= 00 ret-fib= 01 ret-fib= 03 ret-fib= 05 ret-fib= 01 ret-fib= 00 ret-fib= 01 ret-fib= 01 ret-fib= 03 ret-fib= 01 ret-fib= 00 ret-fib= 01 ret-fib= 03 ret-fib= 01 ret-fib= 00 ret-fib= 01 ret-fib= 01 ret-fib= 03 ret-fib= 05 ret-fib= 07`.

Expected results are the first 7 Fibonacci numbers for the input `7`.

```
  identification division.
   program-id. fib recursive.

   data division.
   working-storage section.
   01  numb pic 9 value 7.
   01 result1 pic 9(2).
   01 result2 pic 9(2).

   local-storage section.
   01  num pic 99.
   01  ret-fib pic 9(2).

   procedure division.

       move numb TO num.

       EVALUATE num
       WHEN 0
       move 0 to ret-fib

       WHEN  1
        move 1 to ret-fib

       WHEN OTHER
         compute num = num - 1
         move num to numb
         call "fib" using  num
         move num to result1
         compute num = num - 1
         move num to numb
         call "fib" using num
         move num to result2
          compute ret-fib = result1 + result2
       END-EVALUATE
          display 'ret-fib= ' ret-fib.
        goback.
```

Comment: See, http://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Recursive_14

Comment: Link provided not giving correct results

Comment: *not giving correct results* is not helpful. The Fibonacci sequence is `0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, . . .`. Expecting `5` and got `8` would be helpful. Please provide what you were expecting and what you got.

Comment: a) how does fib get called intially?  b)  I suggest you use larger value declarations; pic 9(2) only allows a 2 digit answer.  If you want to compute fib(x) for any x>=12 you'll get the wrong result.

Answer (score 1):

In the following code, `num` does not contain the value of `ret-fib` after the `call`. This means that neither `result1` nor `result2` will have correct values, except by accident.

```
     move num to numb
     call "fib" using  num
     move num to result1
     compute num = num - 1
     move num to numb
     call "fib" using num
     move num to result2
```

Each call to `fib` and the `PROCEDURE DIVISION` header should have a `RETURNING` phrase to get the value of `ret-fib` into the appropriate `result1` or `result2`.

Further, both `result1` and `result2` should be in the `LOCAL-STORAGE SECTION`, because some calculations using `result1` will be deferred through subsequent calls and different values for `result1` will be used in those calculations.

The standard algorithm for recursive calculation of the nth Fibonacci number uses a main program and a recursive program (function). The recursive program may be a contained program (2002). Trying to do both within a single COBOL program can be done (using the non-standard `ENTRY` statement). It adds unnecessary complications and for that reason is inadvisable.

In order to get the first 7 Fibonacci numbers using recursion, it necessary to call the recursive program (function) for each of the values `0` through `6`.

Answer (score 0):

well I am 1 year and 9 months late to this party, but I have been trying my hand at learning cobol over the last few weeks myself, and was working hard at this very question as I was trying to learn and understand cobol.
Better late than never I hope and here is my code for a working version of this program.

```
   identification division.
   program-id. fibonacci.

   data division.
   working-storage section.
   01  ws-numb-to-solve           PIC 9(10).
   01  ws-solution                PIC 9(10).


   procedure division.
   display "What index of the fibonacci sequence would you like to "
   "find?".
   accept ws-numb-to-solve.
   
   call "recsolve" using by reference ws-numb-to-solve  ws-solution.
   
   display ws-solution.
   
   STOP RUN.

   end program fibonacci.

  *=================================================================

   identification division.
   program-id. recsolve recursive.

   data division.
   local-storage section.
   01  local-numb-to-solve1       PIC 9(10).
   01  local-numb-to-solve2       PIC 9(10).
   01  local-solution1            PIC 9(10).
   01  local-solution2            PIC 9(10).

   linkage section.
   01  ls-numb-to-solve           PIC 9(10).
   01  ls-solution                PIC 9(10).
   
   procedure division 
   using by reference ls-numb-to-solve ls-solution.
   
   EVALUATE ls-numb-to-solve

   WHEN 0

   MOVE 0 TO ls-solution

   WHEN 1

   MOVE 1 TO ls-solution

   WHEN OTHER

   compute local-numb-to-solve1 = ls-numb-to-solve - 1
   compute local-numb-to-solve2 = local-numb-to-solve1 - 1

   call "recsolve" using 
   by reference local-numb-to-solve1 local-solution1 

   call "recsolve" using 
   by reference local-numb-to-solve2 local-solution2 
   
   compute ls-solution = local-solution1 + local-solution2

   END-EVALUATE.
   end program recsolve.
```

The people over at GNUcobol suggest that returning is not necessary here as we can send the reference to a specific variable to a called program by using the "call 'program name' using by reference 'variables to be referenced' " this acts like sending a pointer in c to a function call. The referenced variables get sent to the variables in the linkage section of the called program, and from there any changes made to those variables can be seen by the calling program.
Hope this helps anyone coming by this old post looking for answers.